# How to get value from sharedPreferences in Android Application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i try to make an application that will store our name. so at the first time we run this application, it will ask your name (let's say it on "activityOne"). then write it on sharedPreferences.
So when we run it for the next time, application(activityOne) will read the sharedPreferences. if it's null it will ask you to write your name. but if it have your name, it will go to the next activity(let's say it "activityTwo"). so this piece of my code at oncreate() in "activityOne" :

```
 SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (sp.getString("name", null).equals("false")
            || sp.getString("name", null) != null) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
              activityOne.this.startActivity(new Intent(activityOne.this, activityTwo.class));
          }
        }
        , 20L);
    };
```

So when i run the application for the next time. I didn't need to reinput my name. it will go to the next activity.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value like:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("UserName", "userName);
    editor.commit();
```

and Get the value like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
prefs.getString("UserName","");
```

You are asking about logic,You need to do your effort.Anyhow try this

```
private SharedPreferences dhj;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dhj = this.getSharedPreferences("DHJ", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    if(dhj.getString("username", null) != null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // do some stuff...
    }
    else {
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = dhj.edit();
                    editor .putString("username", username.getText().toString());
                    editor .putString("password", password.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit(); 
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                }
            }); 

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry. but i have been do that. But that i want is when i close the application and then run it for the second time. i want it so look there is value of "name" or not. if it get the value it will go to next activity. but if the value of "name" is null, it will ask you to input your name.

so you didn't need to write your name everytime you run this application

Comment: @mas_bejo See the second parameter in prefs.getString("UserName","") ? That's what is returned if no value is stored. So just check if the value you get .equals("").